# Как получить документы из индекса elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Помогите пожалуйста получить данные из индекса эластика.

Ситуация следующая - в массиве **availability** имеем доступность определенных номеров в гостинице на каждый день (в примере на 2 недели).

Ключами в массиве являются id номеров. Значениями массива выступают вложенные массивы с ключом-датой и доступностью(1 - доступен для бронирования, 0 - недоступен).

Нужно послать запрос так, чтобы вернулись гостиницы, у которых на определенные дни, **хотя бы в одном** из номеров, стояло значение 1 (доступно).

Документы имеют следующий маппинг:

```
[_index] => placement
[_type] => hotel
[_id] => 26
[_version] => 15
[found] => 1
[_source] => Array
    (
        [id] => 26
        [name] => Гостиница 1
        [type_id] => 1
        [review_count] => 65
        [order_count] => 429
        [spa_id] => 3
        [object_id] => 4
        [spa] => 3
        [availability] => Array
            (
                [258] => Array
                    (
                        [2016-03-30] => 0
                        [2016-03-31] => 1
                        [2016-04-01] => 0
                        [2016-04-02] => 0
                        [2016-04-03] => 1
                        [2016-04-04] => 1
                        [2016-04-05] => 0
                        [2016-04-06] => 0
                        [2016-04-07] => 0
                        [2016-04-08] => 1
                        [2016-04-09] => 0
                        [2016-04-10] => 1
                        [2016-04-11] => 1
                        [2016-04-12] => 1
                        [2016-04-13] => 1
                    )

                [259] => Array
                    (
                        [2016-03-30] => 0
                        [2016-03-31] => 1
                        [2016-04-01] => 0
                        [2016-04-02] => 0
                        [2016-04-03] => 0
                        [2016-04-04] => 1
                        [2016-04-05] => 0
                        [2016-04-06] => 0
                        [2016-04-07] => 0
                        [2016-04-08] => 1
                        [2016-04-09] => 1
                        [2016-04-10] => 1
                        [2016-04-11] => 1
                        [2016-04-12] => 1
                        [2016-04-13] => 1
                    )

                [260] => Array
                    (
                        [2016-03-30] => 0
                        [2016-03-31] => 0
                        [2016-04-01] => 0
                        [2016-04-02] => 0
                        [2016-04-03] => 0
                        [2016-04-04] => 0
                        [2016-04-05] => 0
                        [2016-04-06] => 0
                        [2016-04-07] => 0
                        [2016-04-08] => 1
                        [2016-04-09] => 1
                        [2016-04-10] => 1
                        [2016-04-11] => 1
                        [2016-04-12] => 1
                        [2016-04-13] => 1
                    )
            )

        )

     )
```

Вот какой запрос я пытался отправить, использую клиент для PHP:

```
array(4) {
  ["index"]=>
  string(9) "placement"
  ["type"]=>
  string(5) "hotel"
  ["size"]=>
  int(1000)
  ["body"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["query"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["bool"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["must"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          array(1) {
            ["term"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["spa_id"]=>
              int(3)
            }
          }
          [2]=>
          array(1) {
            ["bool"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["must"]=>
              array(5) {
                [0]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["term"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["availability.2016-04-09"]=>
                    int(1)
                  }
                }
                [1]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["term"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["availability.2016-04-10"]=>
                    int(1)
                  }
                }
                [2]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["term"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["availability.2016-04-11"]=>
                    int(1)
                  }
                }
                [3]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["term"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["availability.2016-04-12"]=>
                    int(1)
                  }
                }
                [4]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["term"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["availability.2016-04-13"]=>
                    int(1)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что, указывая в блоке must несколько дат, ты хочешь, чтобы выполнялись ВСЕ условия. А хотя бы в одном - это как по мне should. А вообще запили маппинг и данные сюда: https://www.found.no/play/ Тогда можно будет посмотреть. Важен маппинг: какие ты поля индексируешь и как. Ты привел данные и запрос, а маппинга - нет

Answer (score 1):

Не имея маппинга трудно дать однозначно правильное решение. Судя по всему поле availability используется как объект ({"type":"object"}). В данном случае придется перечислять все возможные номера в bool → should. Т.е. нужно знать все номера, а это плохо.

Лучше использовать следующую структуру

```
"availability": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "room_number": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "available_dates": {
            "type": "array"
        },
    }
}
```

В available_dates записывать даты, в которые номер доступен.

Тогда получить все гостиницы, в которых есть доступные номера на определенные даты можно так:

```
"nested":{
    "path":"availability",
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "filter":[
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "availability.available_dates": [
                            "2016-04-10",
                            "2016-04-11"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```